# Override Only Some Items via list-style

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to override the bullets in a hierarchical arrangement of ordered and unordered lists in HTML nested arbitrarily deep, but only for some items.  The nesting portion of this problem is important because browsers will assign different bullets to lists based on the depth of the list, so using a static override for items that are not checked/unchecked/etc is not an option.

I've put together [a JSFiddle outlining this issue](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/32tkbvwy/6/) and the code is below in case JSFiddle is unavailable.  In the fiddle the items named "noncheck" should have the default bullet styles.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="check"></div></div>checked</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="check"></div></div>checked</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="check"></div></div>checked</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="check"></div></div>checked</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>x</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>x</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x"></div></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checkbox"><div class="x2"></div></div>x</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><div class="checked"></div>noncheck</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 19px;
}
li {
    text-indent: -19px;
    position: relative;
    left: 38px;
    margin-right: 38px;
}
.checkbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
.checkbox > .check {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -11px 0px 0px 18px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.checkbox > .check:before {
    content: '✔';
    color: #000000;
}
.checkbox > .x {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -3px 0px 0px 19px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
.checkbox > .x:before {
    content: '✖';
    color: #000000;
}
.checkbox > .x2 {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -6px 0px 0px 18px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.checkbox > .x2:before {
    content: '✕';
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want those list items which contain `div.checkbox` to have no bullets, and the list items that don't, to behave normally? CSS doesn't allow that, sorry. You will have to rethink your strategy, for instance in the form of assigning the classes to the list items themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this is being programmatically-generated, the `<div class="checkbox">` components are entirely arbitrary.  What I'm trying to do is use the built-in browser bullet style for some subset of items (flagged them in some way to be recognized by the code generating the `HTML` is fine, but tracking which level they are on and which browser would not be.)  If you take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/32tkbvwy/9/) you should notice slightly different bullets for different depths - that's what I'm trying to preserve for arbitrarily chosen items.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. Don't hide the bullets on every li and then try to restore them to what they would have been for some li's only. _Keep_ the bullets on every li and then hide then when they should be hidden. Like I said, assign classes to the list items that should have their bullets hidden, and use css to hide the bullets on those list items only. No need to keep track of which nesting level they are in!

Comment: How would you hide them per `<li>` without using the `list-style: none;` option in the parent `<ul>`?  When I try to just draw checkboxes over them I end up with bullets overlapping and would definitely prefer not to set a background color to the boxes because that's something I won't know the value of at the time the HTML and CSS is generated.

Comment: Don't assign `list-style` to the `ul`; only assign it to the appropriate `li` elements. The `list-style` property on the `ul` itself doesn't do anything, but it is inherited by the list items to produce the bullets. See the [official definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-CSS2-971104/lists.html#propdef-list-style).

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, [that got it](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/32tkbvwy/12/) - if you want to post this suggestion as an answer I'll accept it.  On a related note if you have an idea of [how to reset an arbitrary list level as root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433119/reset-ul-bullets-to-root-level-appearance/) that would be appreciated too, if not thank you for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those list items which contain divs with class "checkbox" to have no bullets, and the list items that don't, to behave normally, the most straightforward solution should have been a CSS selector for "li that contains div.checkbox". Unfortunately, CSS doesn't allow that.

One possible solution is to programmatically assign assign classes to the list items that should have their bullets suppressed.

Since the HTML is created server side on your end, setting those classes shouldn't be too hard.
In the below example, I simulate the same with Javascript (since StackSnippets don't have a server side). Note that this leaves the original HTML unchanged; but this is just for demonstration purposes.
I also changed the CSS a bit, since you don't want to suppress the bullets on all `li` elements, just the ones the checkbox appears in.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
  if (items[i].children.length && items[i].children[0].className == 'checkbox')
    items[i].setAttribute('class', 'checkitem');
```

```css
ul.checklist {
}
ul.checklist > li {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem {
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    text-indent: -18px;
    position: relative;
    left: 38px;
    margin-right: 37px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.check {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -11px 0px 0px 17px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.check:before {
    content: '✔';
    color: #000000;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.x {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -3px 0px 0px 18px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.x:before {
    content: '✖';
    color: #000000;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.x2 {
    border: 0px;
    margin: -6px 0px 0px 17px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul.checklist > li.checkitem > div.checkbox > div.x2:before {
    content: '✕';
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    root node example
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="checklist">
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>checked
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>checked
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>x
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>x
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x"></div>
    </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x2"></div>
    </div>x2
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x2"></div>
    </div>x2
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="x2"></div>
    </div>x2
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </div>checked
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox"></div>unchecked
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="check"></div>
        </div>checked
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x"></div>
        </div>x
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x"></div>
        </div>x
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x"></div>
        </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x2"></div>
        </div>x2
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x2"></div>
        </div>x2
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <div class="x2"></div>
        </div>x2
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checked"></div>noncheck
  </li>
</ul>
```